# Generic method that can return different types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a base abstract class which is meant to allow implementors to return different types:

```
protected abstract T GetMyValue<T>();
```

I would like the implementing class to be able to do something like this:

```
T myResult;    
public override T GetMyValue<T>()
{

     return _myResult;
}
```

I would like the caller to specify the type:

```
int i = obj.GetMyValue<int>();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes... but you will need to supply a suitable conversion to T.  You currently have no constraints, so what if I call `GetMyValue<Flob>`?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what types can be returned?  Seems like overkill when you could just say `int i = 5`.  Will you know the return type at compile time or run time?

Comment: Every class that inherits the base class will have its own set of constraints

Comment: Do you want a given type that has the method `GetMyValue` to be able to return ANY type, or do you want type, `A.GetMyValue` to only be able to return certain types and type, `B.GetMyValue` to be able to only return other, different types?

Comment: The methods can return any type or they can be constrained where each implementor restricts it to 2-4 types (its not that big of a deal for this scenario). I know if I change GetMyValue to return Object it gives me what I want, but I was trying to use generics instead primarily for performance not so much type-checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would just be to store the field as an object. This will cause boxing for structs, but there isn't better way without a more significant change.

```
class Derived : Base
{
     private object o;

     protected override T GetMyValue<T>()
     {
        if (o is T)
           return (T)o;

        return default(T);
     }
}
```

You can't really have a generic field unless the abstract class is itself generic, not the specific method. Of course this is a significant design change. One implementation can now only return one type. Something like

```
abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    protected abstract T GetMyValue();
}

class Derived : Base<int>
{
    private int i;

    protected override int GetMyValue()
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to make the method return Object instead, that way each class does not have to worry about casting rather only the caller casts appropriately.

Comment: @cppNoob It all depends on who you want to put that work on. Someone is going to be casting. The question is should it be easier for the implementer of `Derived` or the caller.

Answer (score 3):

Like an object extension?

```
public static class ObjectExtension
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this object obj)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

        if (converter == null)
            return default(T);

        return (T)converter.ConvertFrom(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for if you want a method on a class.

Comment: This answer happened to be super close to the full extension method I was writing.

Answer (score 0):

You somehow have to make the field have the same type that you want to return. Here's a trick for that:

```
public override T GetMyValue<T>()
{
     return ValueHolder<T>.GetMyValue();
}

class ValueHolder<T> {
 static T myResult;    
 public static T GetMyValue()
 {
     return myResult;
 }
}
```

Because this is a static class there can only be one such value.

If you want to have one value per type *in your instance* you need a `Dictionary<Type, object>`.